# Kotlin: access companion data in generic function

Tags: kotlin, generics, enums

I have a simple task in Kotlin of listing enum values:

```
interface DisplayableEnum<E: Enum<E>> {
    val displayValue: String
}

inline fun <reified T> printAllValues(selected: T?) where T: Enum<T>, T: DisplayableEnum<T> {
    println("All Values:")
    enumValues<T>().forEach {
        println(it.displayValue)
    }
    selected?.let { println("\nSelected: ${it.displayValue}") }
}


////// USAGE

enum class MyEnum(override val displayValue: String): DisplayableEnum<MyEnum> {
    A("value is A"),
    B("value is B")
}

fun main() {
    // with a selected value
    f(MyEnum.A)

    // without a selected value
    f(null as MyEnum?)
}
```

Now imagine that all the enums I pass to `printAllValues` should also have a field called `defaultValue`. In case of `MyEnum` I would write it the following way:

```
enum class MyEnum(override val displayValue: String): DisplayableEnum<MyEnum> {
    A("value is A"),
    B("value is B");

    companion object {
        val defaultValue = A
    }
}
```

So my question: **is there a way to define such a contract in Kotlin?**

Ideally, I would like to somehow define that contract in an interface, like `DisplayableEnum` above, and then somehow use it in `printAllValues` like this:

```
inline fun <reified T> printAllValues(selected: T) where T: Enum<T>, T: DisplayableEnum<T> {
    println("All Values:")
    enumValues<T>().forEach {
        println(it.displayValue)
    }
    selected?.let { println("\nSelected: ${it.displayValue}") }
    println("Default value: ${T.defaultValue???}"
}
```

The one thing that I don't want is using non-companion `defaultValue`, I always have to either pass it to the function manually (but why if the type contains all the info?) or, if made non-companion:

```
interface DisplayableEnum<E: Enum<E>> {
    val displayValue: String
    val defaultValue: E
}
```

then access it through an object - do something ugly like `enumValues<T>().first().defaultValue`.

I wonder if Kotlin has a solution in this case.

Comment: No, Companions are completely different object, you can't reference them through instance of some other class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to define abstract properties in companion object.
So it should be defined in interface directly.

The tricky part here is implementing of this interface without compiler warnings:

```kotlin
enum class MyEnum(override val displayValue: String) : DisplayableEnum<MyEnum> {
    A("value is A"),
    B("value is B");

    override val defaultValue: MyEnum by lazy { A }
}
```

If `enumValues<T>().first().defaultValue` looks ugly to you, wrap it into auxilary function:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> enumDefaultValue(): T where T : Enum<T>, T : DisplayableEnum<T> =
    enumValues<T>().first().defaultValue

//Usage:
println("Default value: ${enumDefaultValue<T>()}")
```

Comment: Thanks for making it more efficient for me, I used `override val defaultValue get() = A` instead of lazy, didn't think of it.